# How change encoding?

Tags: c#, encoding

I need convert or set encoding windows-1251

```
Process p = new Process();
StreamWriter sw;
StreamReader sr;
StreamReader err;



ProcessStartInfo psI = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd");
psI.UseShellExecute = false;

psI.RedirectStandardInput = true;
psI.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
psI.RedirectStandardError = true;
psI.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.StartInfo = psI;


p.Start();
sw = p.StandardInput;
sr = p.StandardOutput;
err = p.StandardError;



sw.AutoFlush = true;
if (tbComm.Text != "")
    sw.WriteLine(tbComm.Text);
else
    //execute default command
    sw.WriteLine("dir \\");


sw.Close();

textBox1.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();// this not support russian word. I need convert or set encoding windows-1251
textBox1.Text += err.ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to [specify the encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.standardoutputencoding.aspx) for the `StandardOutput` on your `ProcessStartInfo` before you point your `StreamReader` to it.

Comment: psI.StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251); - not help me. mayby change StreamReader encoding ?

Comment: @simply denis: I may be wrong, but I think the `StreamReader` encoding can only be set at construction time.  After that it's read-only.  Since it's being constructed within the `Process` then it'll need to be set on the `Process` or on the `ProcessStartInfo` somehow.  I _think_ (I'm not in front of a compiler right now to test).